# My first django project

Tags: django

I started going through The Definitive Guide to Django and now would like to start working on my own project.  I have Django set up and everything.  I created a project called djangoproject1.  Basically what I would like is that the main page is a registration/login page.  My urls.py for djangoproject1 looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/',include('djangoproject1.authentication.urls')),
)
```

I have a pydev package (application) under djangoproject1 called authentication which has an urls.py that looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',direct_to_template,{'template':'index.html'}),
)
```

A couple of questions:

1. I'm getting a page not found error which means I'm probably doing my mapping/include incorrectly
2. If I don't specify anything under TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py, my understanding is that Django will look in each package for a directory named templates.  Is that correct?

Comment: are you getting the 404 when you just try hitting the root of your local dev server?

Comment: I thought that the urlpattern that I specified WAS for the root (http://localhost:8000/).  This results in 404 error.

Comment: try changing your include('djangoproject1... pattern to r'' instead of r'^/'

Comment: That almost worked.  It works if I just say index.html.  But in your comment below you said to specify the full path to my template so I'm not sure how to do that correctly.  'djangoproject1.authentication.templates.index.html'?  That doesn't work but is that approximately what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: using index.html should be fine if you're using the app_directories template loader, otherwise do "djangoproject1/authentication/templates/index.html" and make sure that "djangoproject1" is in your TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py

Comment: I put this under TEMPLATE_DIRS: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),

Then in urls.py I put this:
r'^$',direct_to_template,{'template':'djangoproject1/authentication/templates/index.html'}),

but still getting template not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Asinox has said is not true. You MAY have a global template directory, even several of them. But that is not a must.

In fact template loading is done as follows:

1. Django takes first class name from `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` settings variable
2. It instantiates the template loader based on its name
3. It tries to load the template using this instance
4. If it succeeds - the template is returned
5. If if fails to load the template - it takes the next name and starts over again from 2.
6. If none of the template loaders listed in `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` managed to load the template `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception is raised

By default `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` is set to

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)
```

As Matthew stated `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is used solely by `filesystem.load_template_source` loader. So if you exclude it from the list it won't have any impact on template loading process at all.

In order for your template to be found I'd suggest you to do the following:

- Make your index.html namespaced, i.e. put it as follows:

```
.
`-- djangoproject1
    `-- authentication
        `-- templates
            `-- authentication
                `-- index.html
```

- Load the template namespaced:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'authentication/index.html'}),
    )
```

Unless you do so you cannot be sure that Django loads index.html from the authentication application.

Consider the behavior of `app_directories.load_template_source` template loader.

Pretend you have just defined two applications *app1* and *app2* (no other apps are defined) and asked to load template 'path/to/template.html'.

The loader will check the following paths in no particular order:

- project_root/app1/templates/path/to/template.html
- project_root/app2/templates/path/to/template.html

Comment: So really if I use the app_directories loader only, I don't need the file system loader and don't need the template_dirs.  By namespacing my templates like you did it works perfectly.   Thanks

Comment: this namespacing only works until you get templates/main/index.html in multiple apps...

Comment: I'll have to keep my names different for the time being I guess

Answer (score 1):

Django will NOT automatically look for a templates directory, but there is a template loader (that comes by default) in settings.py called django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader that will.  I reccomend NOT using this because it does not namespace your templates.  This means that a template called index.html under an appone/templates will hide a template called index.html under apptwo/templates (if apptwo is below appone in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: having said that - you SHOULD still have a templates directory under each app to organize your templates, but I would recommend always explicitly listing full paths to your templates so you're sure that you know which one you're getting.

Comment: thanks, thats a helpful hint!
so in my urls.py in the authentication package, what should my template dictionary specify?  'djangoproject1.authentication.templates.index.html'?  That seems wrong because templates isn't a package

Comment: correct, it isn't a package, it is just a file on the file system. "djangoproject1/authentication/templates/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Django will search in other place's, but you NEED a template directory under your project.

Comment: I made sure to put a templates directory under the main project as well as one under my authentication package.  I think the problem is with how I'm including.